# 'gdi+ generic error' when I try to update one register

Tags: vb.net

To save the image from my form to my database I use this code in the function `SaveData`

```
If Not IsNothing(_Image) Then
    Dim _MemStream As New MemoryStream()
    _Image.Save(_MemStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", _MemStream.ToArray()).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image
Else
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", Nothing)
End If
```

That works fine when the info is saved for the first time but when I try to update another field in the register gives me the error `gdi+ generic error` and the output `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException` I use the same function for save and update the info.

Serching for this problem I found this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and in the condition explanation says `The image was saved with the wrong image format or the image was saved to the same file it was created from.` so I think that the problem comes because the data from the Image field is the same that the data I send to be save(update). **How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, when I tried to edit the info I was using this:

```
Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(DirectCast(DataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(10).Value, Byte()))
    PictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
End Using
```

But that don't let me edit the register so I tried with this:

```
Dim b() As Byte = DataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(10).Value
Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(b)
PictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

I think both ways do the same but only work with the second.